# Python writerow() from the CSV library is throwing KeyError

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have the below code, I am trying to write the contents of the dictionary to a CSV file.

```py
import csv

my_dict = {
    "Power outage": 3,
    "System overload": 3,
    "Pasta not aldente": 3,
    "No internet": 2,
    "No red marker": 1,
}

with open("testCsv.csv", "w", newline="") as file:
    fieldnames = ["Type", "Count"]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, delimiter=",", fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    for k, v in my_dict.items():
        writer.writerow({my_dict[k], my_dict[v]})
file.close()
```

When I run the file I get the below error, can't find any answer or hint online.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "csvWrite.py", line 17, in <module>
    writer.writerow({my_dict[k], my_dict[v]})
KeyError: 3
```

Comment: Check out [dictwriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).  1) fieldnames should be the same as dictionary keys.  2) you give writerrow the entire dictionary, i.e. writer.writerow(my_dict) (i.e. you don't loop over k, v pairs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you iterate correctly through the `my_dict` and assign key-value pairs before writing to CSV.

```py
import csv

my_dict = {
    "Power outage": 3,
    "System overload": 3,
    "Pasta not aldente": 3,
    "No internet": 2,
    "No red marker": 1,
}

with open("testCsv.csv", "w", newline="") as file:
    fieldnames = ["Type", "Count"]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, delimiter=",", fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    for key in my_dict:
        writer.writerow({fieldnames[0]: key, fieldnames[1]: my_dict[key]})
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the line `writer.writerow({my_dict[k], my_dict[v]})` with `writer.writerow({"Type": k, "Count": v})`. I guess you are tried to access 3 (on the first line) which is the value of "Power outage" but not presents in my_dict keys.
You also don't need to add `file.close()` `with` statement handles it.